# How to remove entire profile from thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

I did what has been warned; be careful when entering the config in Thunderbird. I trashed it. I cannot get to the 'options' at all to correct. I uninstalled Thunderbird; then reinstalled it (via the app store). Sadly, when I reinstall, it reinstalls the trashed thunderbird. How do I go in and completely remove the entire program so that it is a clean install, instead of reinstalling the same trashed app that I ruined? Steps, please. I figure it must have something to do with profiles, but I don't know exactly what to do. HELP.

Comment: You should be able to close Thunderbird and then remove everything (probably even the directory itself) from ~/.thunderbird before opening Thunderbird back up. That should generate a completely new profile.

Comment: @KGIII that's a good answer. Consider making it a real answer so we can upvote it.

Comment: I finally just reinstalled the entire OS, however, after a lot more reading, I figured out that without the Explorer window and the settings to show hidden files in the GUI, I would not have been able to follow those instructions, since i didn't at the time know how to get to the hidden files. (now I do; however, I would likely have been afraid to remove anything via the command line, still not sure, but thanks. For normal, smart enough users, your answer likely make perfect sense.